Calculations using parabola
I've had quite a few calculations that can be done with parabola, so I think it's a good idea to collect them in one place, I'm asking this question maybe my list will be expanded, maybe reference sources for some methods, and evidence is also welcome, so let's start
Product:

Arithmetic mean:


Geometric mean:


Harmonic mean:


Average square root:

Half the difference:

Calculating the product using a parabola and the second way to find the geometric mean I saw them before somewhere but I forgot, the rest of the methods I found them myself.

This can be added to the list https://nrich.maths.org/problems/parabella

James Tanton's Parabolic Multiplication: https://www.jamestanton.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Cool-Math-Essay_OCTOBER-2014_Parabolic-Multiplication1.pdf
